# Publish on Facebook page with PHP

Tags: php, facebook

I was using CURL to publish on Facebook page but now it's not working anymore.

I need to publish on Facebook page using GraghAPI and CURL from my website to my pages.

This was code used before it was working for about 4 months ago but now not working:

```
$page_access_token = 'PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN';
$page_id = 'PAGE_ID';
$data['picture'] = $news_image;
$data['link'] = $url_link;
$data['message'] = $title;
$data['caption'] = $title;
$data['description'] = $disc;
$data['access_token'] = $page_access_token;
$post_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $page_id . '/feed';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === FALSE) {
    die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);
```

How to publish to Facebook page without using Facebook App as it need a lot of verification to make an app.

Comment: So what is not working?

Comment: You may need to renew the access token, whats the response in `$result`?

Comment: Access tokens are typically good for somewhere between an hour and 60 days. Four months almost certainly means your old token expired.

Comment: I've tried many times with access token but nothing is posted in Facebook page.

Comment: I've found issue as you told me from $result